# Make Javascript calculate HTML input from user

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a website that can calculate the numbers that the user enters in the text field. Below, I am trying to store the users input in a variable and then return it to the console, but this does not seem to work. It is supposed to take in more calculations down the line, but I thought I would keep it simple at first.
What have i forgotten?

PS: I'm currently still learning JavaScript, so don't roast me too hard :)

Thanks!

Best
Mikkel

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <script src="/JavaScript/culjo.js" defer></script>
        <title>Culjo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Culjo</h1>

    <input id="inputOne" type="text">
    <input id="inputtwo" type="text">
    <input id="result" type="number">





    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256- 
    QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script 
    src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Javascript

```
        function calculate() {
        var inputOne = document.getElementById("inputOne")
        var inputTwo = document.getElementById("inputTwo")
            result = inputOne+inputTwo + inputTwo
            
            return result
    }
    calculate()
```

Comment: I imagine you have forgotten to turn the string inputs into numbers. But please detail specifically what is not working.

Comment: you probably need to `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` the text box values otherwise they will be strings and will just concatenate instead of add

Comment: also you missed off the `.value` (to get the value entered in the textbox) - eg `inputOne.value`.  And finally, you don't do anything with the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the value of the field like this:

```
var inputOne = document.getElementById("inputOne").value;
```

and then use

`parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` as stated at the comments to parse the string.

Comment: var result = parseInt(inputOne) + parseInt(inputTwo); or var result = parseFloat(inputOne) + parseFloat(inputTwo); as reference because you mentioned you were still learning, goodluck ;)

Comment: Thank you very much, all of you!
I will get back to you as soon as I know if it works! :)

Comment: It worked like a charm! I actually found another solution:
In stead of using parseInt, you can just put in "+" instead and that does the same like so:
var result = +inputOne + +inputTwo
It works with floating point numbers as well.